# Frappe ERPNext and quickbooks connector

Tags: quickbooks-online, erpnext, frappe

I am a python developer. I need to build a connector that will sync customers between ERPNext and quickbooks(using quickbooks API). How can I achieve that? please refer me socs if available for such erpnext customization.

Comment: What version/year/edition of QuickBooks? What sort of data? What research have you done so far? What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I can help you with that. Currently i have QuickBooks connections using Ruby and also C#..

Comment: thanks for your response. I have built odoo-quickbooks connector already. I am facing problem in ERPNext configurations in pycharm to start development.

Comment: there are Quickbooks and Tally migration tools available in ERPNext. Check them out and if you have any improvements to share, that'd be great :)

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend you to below options:

1) Frappe built in REST API functionality is the easiest and most reliable way to integrate with different systems. You can prepare a script or a software which will transfer customer data by means of APIs each other.

For full-duplex sync:
step-1: Retrieve erpnext new customers (or updates) via its API
step-2: Post new customers to quickbooks database via its API function
step-3: Retrieve new quickbooks customers (or updates) via its API
step-4: Post new customers to erpnext database via its API function

You can run that script periodically in the OS scheduler.

2) You can create replication task alternatively if your quickbooks implementation use Mariadb or Mysql database.